# How a WCF request can be correlated with multiple Workflow instances?

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

The scenario is a follow:

I have multiple clients in which they can register themselves on a workflow server, using WCF requests, to receive some kind of notifications. The information of the notifications will be received from an external system using another receive activity. The workflow then should get the notification information and callback all registered clients using send activity and callback correlations (the clients are exposing callback interfaces implemented in there and the end-point addresses passed initially with the registration requests). "Log-running workflow service" approach is used with a persistent storage.

Now, I'm looking for some way to correlate the incoming information of the notifications received from the external system with the persisted workflow instances created previously when the registration requests, so that all clients will be notified using end-points that already passed with the registration requests. Is WF 4.0 capable of resuming and executing multiple workflow instances when the information of the notification received without storing end-points somehow manually and go though them? If yes, how can I do that?

Also, if my approach of doing so is not correct, then please advice me about the best practice of doing such system using WCF services.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use request correlation with workflow services the correlation key must always match a single workflow instance, you can't have multiple workflow instances react to a single message. So you either need to multicast the message using all the different correlation keys or resume you workflow instances in some other way. That other way could be to store the request somewhere, like a SQL table, and have the workflows periodically check that location if they need to notify the client.